# Responsive header image - change image with css

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I looked around but found nothing, I was wondering is it possible to change the header's img when you try to make a responsive website?

For example: show normal img when screen width is more than 800px and when you go below 800px replace that img with another one.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at http://api.jquery.com/resize/ , event for windows size  change

Comment: I would prefer not to use javascript though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 media queries to achieve responsive web design.

Let us assume you have a header with id : headerID

default css:

```
 #headerId {
        background: url("default-image-url.png");
    }
```

Then you just need to add the following to your CSS file:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #headerId {
        background: url("different-image-url.png") !important;
    }
}
```

Then in your HTML at the `<head>` add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: It seems the whole site "eats" up the banner img now. I mean the whole website content went up where the img used to be before.

Comment: You need to specify the height and width for the header. I have mentioned only about the background image. The remaining height & width you need to specify

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle i can help you on that itself.. else provide the required HTML

Comment: Awesome! I tried playing around with padding which worked, but I am not sure if that was the correct approach. Thank you for the help mate!

Comment: If you could show me the html i could guide you well.. But media queries is the correct approach. if it has solved your issue, then please accept the answer :)

Comment: The only problem I have right now mate, is that the img itself is not responsive anymore. It used to shrink as the screen size would squeeze it. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: background-size: contain; Add this to the media query code, it will fix that issue.

Comment: It works almost perfect now. The only thing that I got problem with is that the new img will be placing itself on the left leaving an empty space on the right screen. hmm :/ Btw mate ty for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery it would be:

```
if ($(window).width() < 800) {
   $('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
   //image when windows is less than 800px  
}
else {
   $('#divID').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
   //image when windows is more than 800px  
}
```

Comment: As in most situations, jQuery is not necessary here

Comment: @JonathonBlok but jQuery is compatible with every browser. I think min-width/max-width is incompatible with old versions of IE

Comment: Thats true. If <=IE8 support is required, OP would need a javascript fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with one `<img>` tag unless you use javascript.

To use CSS only you need to use background images as mohamedrias says, or have two images and show or hide one, based on the screen width by using a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #headerImg1 {
        display: none;
    }
    #headerImg2 {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 801px) {
    #headerImg1 {
        display: block;
    }
    #headerImg2 {
        display: none;
    }
}
```